# Jquery array - set and load values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am having 2 divs:

```
<div id="player" class="setPlayers">value1</div>
<div id="player2" class="setPlayers">value2</div>
```

All I want to do is to set the value1 and value2 of the divs to an array for reading later on; I tried out this code, but doesn' t work:

```
var array = new Array();

$.each($('.setPlayers'), function(key, object) {
    console.log(index + ':' + value);
    array.push(value);
    alert(value);
});

$.each(array, function(index, value) {
    console.log(index + ':' + value);
    console.log(index + ':' + $(this).val());
});​
```

what' s wrong according to you ?,cheers

Comment: Well just as a code review level, where does the variable "value" get declared, in the first each ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your code as a start I came up with:

```
$(function(){
  var array = [];

  $('.setPlayers').each(function(index) {
      console.log(index + ':' + $(this).text());
      array.push($(this).text());
      alert($(this).text());
  });

  $.each(array, function(index) {
      console.log(index + ':' + this);
      console.log(index + ':' + this);
  });
});
```

​

Few too many alerts and debug for my liking.

If you just want to fill the array then this will do:

```
$(function(){
  var array = $('.setPlayers').map(function() { return $(this).text()); }).get();
});
​
```

Comment: Cheers Gerbil, that, exactly what I need, yes indeed many alerts :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this (see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GcjgH/):

```
var array = $('.setPlayers').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

alert(array[0]);
alert(array[1]);
​
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be `$('.setPlayers').each(function(){ ... });`

In the context of the question:

```
$('.setPlayers').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).attr("id")+':'+$(this).text());
     array.push($(this).text());
     alert($(this).text());
});

for (var i=0; i<array.len; i++){
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var array = new Array();
$(".setPlayers").each(function() {
    array.push($(this).text());
});
```